# How to reset .bashrc file which edited before to set PATH ANDROID sdk?

Tags: command-line, android, bashrc

```
 bash: export: `/home/entw/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local /bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/bin': not a valid identifier
 bash: /home/entw/.bashrc: line 111: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
 bash: /home/entw/.bashrc: line 112: syntax error: unexpected end of file
 entw@entw-desktop:~$
```

This is the error I frequently getting in terminal, shows when terminal opened.

The following commands I applied in terminal,

```
sudo gedit $HOME/.bashrc
```

and added some path variable like `android SDK`, and run the following command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then I got the error in terminal

```
bash: export: `/home/entw/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local  /bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/bin': not a valid identifier
bash: /home/entw/.basrc: line 111: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: /home/entw/.bashrc: line 112: syntax error: unexpected end of file
entw@entw-desktop:~$
```

but if I try to open again that file shows the error `file or directory not found`.
what do I do to set all correct?

This forum I tried: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=919425 "--point 2"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to reset .bashrc file which edited before to set PATH ANDROID sdk

The original `.bashrc` is located in `/etc/skel/`. So just run the following command:

`cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~`

That way you can restore your `.bashrc` to the way it was when you created the account for the user.

Regarding the problem you are facing: it would be helpful if you post the content of your `.bashrc`, or at least the code you have altered/added.

Comment: bash: cp: No such file or directory error!!!

Comment: If your `PATH` variable is messed up, you can try `/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~`

Comment: Its worked, without error in terminal!!! Thank you, saved me.

Comment: I am new to this Ubuntu env, can you suggest me any tutorials to follow

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials out there for all different kind of stuff. A good starting point would be https://help.ubuntu.com/community